# How to send and receive mp3 data using Qt UDP socket?

Tags: c++, qt, networking, udp

how do I send a 128kbps mp3 file at a rate of 128Kibps (16KiB / s) using UDP socket in QT. I searched for tutorials, but I found none. Thanks.

Comment: I have an example app, Take a look if it helps: https://github.com/shbobur/UDPPlayer. It sends and receives images using UDP socket. You run two clients and send/receive .jpeg images.

Comment: thanks @Bobur ... I will study your code... and try hahahah

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send large data on UDP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343116/send-large-data-on-udp-socket)